# SSL self-signed certificate for internal services

Tags: security, ssl, https, self-signed-certificate

I have some internal services that I need to secure them with https.

What security issue can happen if I use a self-signed ssl and trust it on all client's systems?

Comment: That depends who has access to the private key of that self-signed certificate.

Comment: Just me.I'm going to generate it on servers and keep them there

Comment: Then there should not be a security problem (assuming the private key is a cryptographically strong key (like RSA 2048) and the used hash algorithm is also not weak (SHA-1 is nowadays considered no longer secure).

Comment: Why not create your own (root) CA? Using self signed certs does not scale; any node that is added will need to have the trust in a new certificate established on all nodes.

Comment: @Robert For 128 bit security and RSA you'd need a 3072 bit key.